# Getting makeObjectsPerformSelector to Work in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use makeObjectsPerformSelector instead of using a loop and I can't quite get it to work. I have like 20 balls that I'm trying to add to the screen inside "init".

I can add a single one by making a sprite like this:

```
CCSprite *ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];

        // set the position of the ball providing the coordinates
        ball.position = ccp((player.contentSize.width/2 + 400)+ball.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2 - ball.contentSize.height/2);

        // add the ball to the playing area
        [self addChild:ball];
```

This seems to work great but now I need to add like 20 of them. So I've decided to use an array  called "balls" and I've read that I can use makeObjectsPerformSelector to perform an action on each each object in the array, but I can't figure out how to add each ball, so far I have this:

```
- (void) makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{

    // add the ball to the screen
    [self addChild:aSelector];

}
```

I think that I need to use the aSelector object on the balls array and add that right? Am I using this incorrectly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, it's rather hard to tell what you're trying to do. But if you have an `NSArray` called `balls`, and an operation you want to perform on each ball called `bounce`, you can use `-makeObjectsPerformSelector:`:

```
[balls makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(bounce)];
```

Was that helpful at all?

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, I believe I am using the wrong method. In order to perform a certain function on each object inside the "balls" array, is the only way to use a for loop? Loop through each one and add it? Thank you for your response

Comment: Like for (id object in array) {
    // do something with object
}

Comment: If the operation you wish to perform on each ball is a method on the ball's class, then you can use `-makeObjectsPerformSelector:` as I demonstrated. If, however, you need to do something more complicated with the balls (such as where the ball is an argument to a message or something, like `[self bounce:ball]`), you will need to use a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

A selector is not an object.  It is a key which is used to look up an implementation in the method table.  You should never need to override `-makeObjectsPerformSelector:`

Comment: Thank you for your response NSResponder, it was helpful